# Turn array element into a function call

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is either a dumb question or one without an answer

I want to call a function by using an element in an array as a way to match the function name. The elements of the array are, and may need to remain string.

i.e

```
   $(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
      var classes = $(this).attr('class'); 
      var classesArr = classes.split(' ');
      
      arr[1]();
   });

   function two() { console.log('hello'); }
```

```
   <a href="foo" class="one two three"></a>
```

obviously this doesn't work, and I get "arr[1] is not a function". But is there a trick?

Comment: The question has no relation to jQuery. I removed the tag accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: How you store/access the string doesn't change the fact that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**eval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to do it

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
eval(arr[1]+'()');

function two() { console.log('hello'); }
```

Or using `window`

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
window[arr[1]]();

function two() { console.log('hello'); }
```

Comment: I thought eval() was to be avoided? I found this as an answer but so many people seemed to say to avoid eval() at all costs as it can be used maliciously. Just curious

Comment: @Then you might be using `windows`,see [use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: do you personally agree that using eval() is a poor idea?

Comment: @JustinRiley It depends on how you using it,there is not absoultely answer for `eval` is ppor or not

Answer (score 2):

Put the function references into the array - instead of their names as strings.

```js
const arr = [one, two, three];
arr[1]();

function one() {console.log('hello one'); }
function two() {console.log('hello, this is two!'); }
function three() {console.log('hello three'); }
```

Comment: The array elements are string because the source of the array is a string. Like so: ```var classes = $(this).attr('class'); var classesArr = classes.split(' ');``` The value of 'class' on link elements are string, e.g 'nav content sub_nav'. Hence the 'jquery' tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `functions` Object and declare functions from that. Global functions are always a property of `window` (the global scope in a browser), so you can refer to them using `window[functionName]`

```js
const functions = {
  one: _ => console.log(`function one`),
  two: _ => console.log(`function two`),
  three: _ => console.log(`function three`)
};

const [one, two, three] = Object.values(functions);
// call 'one'
one();

// or (not advisable) as global (so: window) properties
const names = [`winOne`, `winTwo`, `winThree`];
const [win1, win2, win3] = names.map(n => window[n]);

// call 'win3'
win3();

function winOne() { console.log(`function winOne`); }
function winTwo() { console.log(`function winTwo`); }
function winThree() { console.log(`function winThree`); }
```